# Trying to remove space in digital time. 00 : 00

Tags: python, time

I have some trouble finding out how to remove this space on either side of the `:`.

```
print("END TIME:", EndTimeHour, ":", EndTimeMinute)
```

When I run my code I get a result of `END TIME: 10 : 25`.
I need it to be `10:25`!

Comment: print("END TIME:", EndTimeHour, ":", EndTimeMinute)

Comment: Instead of `,` use `+` this is called string concatenation (or just use string formatting), `print("END TIME:", str(EndTimeHour) + ":" + str(EndTimeMinute))`

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: `print(a,b)` always introduces a space while printing.If you do not want space then `print(a+b)` or `print('{}{}`%(a,b))`.

Comment: @bulbus I think you mean `"%d:%d" % (a, b)`?

Comment: Yes, agree for this case.I assumed a/b to be strings in my case without announcing the same.@cricket_007

Comment: `print('{}:{}'%(a,b))`  when a & b are strings. for this case `print("END TIME:%d:%d"%(EndTimeHour,EndTimeMinute))`

Comment: @bulbus My point was that The `% ()` operator does not work with the `{}` style formatting

Comment: ah right! @cricket_007

Comment: `print('{}:{}'.format(a,b))` or `print('%d:%d'%(a,b))` a & b being `int`. Thx @cricket_007 for correcting. I muddled up old and new format supports earlier

Answer (score 2):

Don't use commas, then. Make it print a *formatted* string.

```
print("END TIME: {}:{}".format(EndTimeHour, EndTimeMinute))
```

When you do put commas within `print()`, it tells the print function to separate the values

Answer (score 1):

would this work?

```
time = "12 : 54"
time = time.split(" ")
time = time[0] + time[1] + time[2]
print(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to use `trim` method's equivalent in Python i.e. `strip`.

You can strip spaces from both sides, right side or left side of the individual strings by using following and then concatenate as per your need

```
str.strip() # trim both sides
str.rstrip() # trim right side only
str.lstrip() # trim left side only
```

Adding clarification so this doesn't get downvoted without understanding the solution.

```
hour.strip() + ":" + minute.strip()
```

Comment: This strips the outside, not inside

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for down voting without understanding question and my solution. Question has both the fields endtime hour and minute as separate string and strip can be used on them individually, concatenate as required and not use strip on the complete string.

Comment: I understood the question was printing with commas in the print statement, so your answer is more "get the string, then strip it" rather than suggesting to simply print the values differently

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys! I just realized that I was smart enough to add a comment when I saw this during class. It was this..... print(8,":",5,sep="")